# can an electric field exist at a point where the electrical potential there is zero?

Tags: calculus, integration, mathematical-physics

can an electric field exist at a point where the electrical potential there is zero? 0
v=integral of E.dl

Comment: Depending on how you set-up the integral there might need to be a minus sign. Of course $\vec{E} = - \nabla V$ so one choice would be $V(r) = -\int_{O}^{r} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{r}$ where $O$ denotes the point where we set $V$ to zero. Often, in physics, we take $O$ to be infinity.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The electric field might be generated for example by two charges: $+5C$ and $-4C$ separated by $2$ meters. There is a point in between them where the potential is $0$ (the electric potential is also $0$ in the infinite) but in that point the electric field vector is not null.

The electric field is related to the derivative of the electric potential so you can draw an analogy to a particle which is undergoing some acceleration. Just because the velocity is zero at some point does not mean that the particle is not accelerating at that point.

Comment: Even a dipole with the charges of the same magnitude and opposite signs works.  The midpoint between the charges has potential zero and has an electric field.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to this question is-----
        In the case of a dipole where two unlike charges are separated by some distance will have electric potential zero and electric field is not zero. It contradicts the relation between electric field and electric potential, i.e., 
                                  $$E=-\dfrac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dR}$$
where

- $E=$ electric field
- $V=$ electric potential
- $R=$ distance between the two unlike charges

Comment: Does this add anything to the previous answer?